# Adding keyboard functionalities to button in flutter (custom keyboard with buttons)

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I can use `TextFormField()` widget effectively. But, some of my users may not have the characters in their keyboard that is needed in my application. So, I want to create a button (raised, flat, material does not matter) and when user taps on the button I want to add some characters that are in the `FormTextField()` already.

Logically code is this:

```
RaisedButton(
    child: Text('ə'),
    onPressed: (){
        input = input + 'ə';                     
    }
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the context of a text field using a [`TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html).

Declaration:

```dart
final _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Assignment:

```dart
TextField( // Or TextFormField
  controller: _controller,
  ...
),
```

Usage:

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('a'),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() => _controller.text += 'a');
  },
),
```

Comment: really appreciated!